# Lenovo ideacentre AIO 3-24ARE05 - Type F0EW broken screen. hdni out will not display until windows loads. stuck in safe mode windows 11

Tags: windows, bios, safe-mode, lenovo-desktop-computer

I cannot see anything on my monitor ie bios setup, windows safe mode, WinRE, etc. I can only view the windows login screen after windows loads.

Spending over $200 on a new display is completely out of my budget for the moment.

What options do I potentially have? Lenovo customer support is about as helpful as asking a hampster what my options are.

Any help would be appreciated as im at a complete loss.

I was hoping to possibly create a vga adapter from the lcd cable out of the motherboard to a vga adapter//plug into my monitor.

My monitor is a HP 23es

Comment: Do you have a second monitor and is it the monitor used after Windows loads?

Comment: There is not much else you can do except replace the screen. Laptop screens are necessary for some laptop activities.

Comment: its not a laptop its an all in one

Comment: yes i have a second monitor but it only powers on at windows login. i never see the initial splash screens

Answer (score 0):

you can install linux or ubuntu via usb and it will boot second screen automatically as the second monitor right click display settings and set to primary display that was all i could come up with after trying windows 7-11